# Efficient way to create a table of yes/no responses

Tags: r

I have a data frame with several thousand responses to binary survey responses (yes/no) to 26 variables (questions); each participant also has a sex variable (male/female). I want to create a table of the proportion of "yes" responses for each of the 26 questions, with separate columns for males and females.

I was able to achieve the desired result by using the code below, but when there are 26 variables involved it seems very inefficient. I am sure there is a better way to do this, perhaps using one of the `*apply` family functions, but I'm not sure how to do so, or even where to begin. Any help is much appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(Sex = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0), Q1 = c(1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1), 
                                               Q2 = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0), 
                                               Q3 = c(0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1))

df$Sex <- factor(df$Sex, levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("Female", "Male"))

table1 <- 100*prop.table(table(df$Q1[df$Sex == "Female"]))
table2 <- 100*prop.table(table(df$Q2[df$Sex == "Female"]))
table3 <- 100*prop.table(table(df$Q3[df$Sex == "Female"]))

m.table <- rbind(table1, table2, table3)
m.table <- m.table[,c(2)]

table4 <- 100*prop.table(table(df$Q1[!df$Sex == "Female"]))
table5 <- 100*prop.table(table(df$Q2[!df$Sex == "Female"]))
table6 <- 100*prop.table(table(df$Q3[!df$Sex == "Female"]))

f.table <- rbind(table4, table5, table6)
f.table <- f.table[,c(2)]

mf.table <- cbind(m.table, f.table)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have yes no response as 1/0, we can take `mean` of question columns. In base R, we can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(.~Sex, df, mean)

#  Sex  Q1  Q2  Q3
#1   0 0.6 0.0 0.4
#2   1 0.6 0.6 0.6
```

---

Using `dplyr` one way would be to `group_by` `Sex` and count the ratio of 1's by taking `mean` of various question columns

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Sex) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with("Q")), mean)


#    Sex    Q1    Q2    Q3
#  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     0   0.6   0     0.4
#2     1   0.6   0.6   0.6
```

Or with `tidyr` and some reshaping

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
   gather(question, value, -Sex) %>%
   group_by(Sex, question) %>%
   summarise(yesratio = mean(value)) %>%
   spread(question, yesratio)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (not necessarily cleaner than @RonakShah's): reshape data from wide to long, compute a table on all three columns, compute proportions, take the "yes" proportions and scale by 100:

```
df_m <- reshape2::melt(df,id.vars="Sex", 
                       variable.name="Variable",
                       value.name="Response")
tt1 <- with(df_m,table(Sex,Variable,Response))
tt2 <- prop.table(tt1,margin=c(1,2))
t(tt2[,,"1"]*100)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `by` from `base R`

```
by(df[-1], df$Sex, colMeans)
#df$Sex: Female
# Q1  Q2  Q3 
#0.6 0.0 0.4 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
#df$Sex: Male
# Q1  Q2  Q3 
#0.6 0.6 0.6
```

---

Or as the OP mentioned efficient use, an option would be `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, mean), Sex]
#     Sex  Q1  Q2  Q3
#1: Female 0.6 0.0 0.4
#2:   Male 0.6 0.6 0.6
```